# How to wait until all geojson feature properties have been iterated in google maps api before printing?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the "forEachProperty" function as follows:

```
map.data.forEach(function(feature) { 
    console.log('>> ', feature.get('letter'), 'properties are: '); 
    var properties = "";
    feature.forEachProperty(function(value,property) {
        console.log(property,':',value);
        properties += property;
    });

    // The line below is an issue as it does not "wait" for the forEachProperty to finish going through all properties.
    console.log(properties);
});
```

How can I wait for forEachProperty to finish going through all the features before logging out the "properties" string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    feature.forEachProperty(function (value, name) {
        // Do something
    });

    resolve();
});

promise.then(function () {
    // All properties loaded, continue.
});
```